# Я хочу сделать чтобы была кнопка в кнопке (и она работала) discord.py discord-components

Tags: discord, discord.py

Код ниже Заранее спасибо)

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    components = [
            Button(label='Тест', style=ButtonStyle.blue, custom_id='blue'),
            Button(label='Тест2', style=ButtonStyle.red, custom_id='red'),
            Button(label='Тееест', style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id='green'),
            Button(label='Тест3', style=ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id='gray'),
            Button(label='URL', style=ButtonStyle.URL, url='http://google.com')
        ]
    
    message = await ctx.send('Тест.', components=components)

    while True:
        interaction = await bot.wait_for(
                'interaction',
                check=lambda inter: inter.message.id == message.id,
                timeout=999999
            )
        if interaction.channel == ctx.channel:
         if interaction.component.label == "Тест":
            await interaction.respond(
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Нажми"),
                components=[
                    Button(style=ButtonStyle.green, label="Yes", custom_id='green'),
                    Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="No", custom_id='red')
                 
                ]
            
            ) 
         if interaction.component.label == "Yes":
            await interaction.respond(content="1. Да")
         if interaction.component.label == "No":
            await interaction.respond(content="2. нет")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь PyQt5.

Comment: Или сделайте с помощью Tkinter кнопку-картинку, а на картинке нарисуйте кнопку в кнопке.

Comment: не знаком с PyQt5 (

Comment: С Tkinter же Вы знакомы?

Comment: к сожалению тоже нет .-.

Comment: А с какой GUI-библиотекой Вы знакомы?

Comment: ахах никакой  ._.

Comment: А как Вы тогда планируете создать кнопку? Или Вам прислать материал?

Comment: Кнопку можно сделать с помощью discord-components, ну и кода .-. Я хочу чтобы он отвечал на кнопку в кнопке. Но у меня не получается. Вот спрашиваю.

Comment: В конструкторе кода Qt Designer можно указатькнопке стили CSS. Поищите в интернете как на CSS сделать кнопку дискорд.